# Regex for checking for compass directions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking to match the 8 main directions as might appear in a street or location prefix or suffix, such as:

- **N** Main
- **south** I-22
- 124 Grover Ave **SE**

This is easy to code using a brute force list of matches and cycle through every match possibility for every street address, matching once with a start-of-string anchor and once with a end-of-string anchor. My blunt starting point is shown farther down, if you want to see it.

**My question** is if anyone has some clever ideas for compact, fast-executing patterns to accomplish the same thing. You can assume:

- Compound directions always start with the north / south component. So I need to match South East but not EastSouth
- The pattern should **not** match [direction]-ern words, like "Northern" or "Southwestern"
- The match will always be at the very beginning or very end of the string.

I'm using C#, but I'm just looking for a pattern so I'm not emphasizing the language. `/s(outh)?/` is just as good as `@"s(outh)?"` for me or future readers.

SO emphasizes real problems, so FYI this is one. I'm parsing a few hundred thousand nasty, unvalidated user-typed address strings. I want to check if the start or end of the "street" field (which is free-form jumble of PO boxes, streets, apartments, and straight up invalid junk) begins or ends with a compass direction. I'm trying to deconstruct these free form strings to find similar addresses which may be accidental or intentional variations and obfuscations.

My blunt attempt

Core pattern: `/n(orth)?|e(ast)?|s(outh)?|w(est)?|n(orth\s*east|e|orth\s*west|w)|s(outh\s*east|e|outh\s*west|w)/`

In a function:

```
public static Tuple<Match, Match> MatchDirection(String value) {
    string patternBase = @"n(orth)?|e(ast)?|s(outh)?|w(est)?|n(orth\s*east|e|orth\s*west|w)|s(outh\s*east|e|outh\s*west|w)";
    Match[] matches = new Match[2];
    string[] compassPatterns = new[] { @"^(" + patternBase + @")\b", @"\b(" + patternBase + @")$" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { matches[i] = Regex.Match(value, compassPatterns[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); }
    return new Tuple<Match, Match>(matches[0], matches[1]);
}
```

In use, where `sourceDt` is a table with all the addresses:

```
var parseQuery = sourceDt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((DataRow row) => {
        string addr = ((string)row["ADDR_STREET"]).Trim();
        Tuple<Match, Match> dirMatches = AddressParser.MatchDirection(addr);
        return new string[] { addr, dirMatches.Item1.Value, dirMatches.Item2.Value };
    })
```

Comment: Don't have a solution just yet, but refiddle.com is a great resource for trying to build these types of patterns cause you can set up a corpus of allowed and not allowed matches: http://refiddle.com/1ol

Comment: Not really a good answer, but have you ran your code against the dataset? I often find that in this kind of scenario, you can't possibly guess all of the possibilities. So, it helps to run the code against the data, and then refine it once you see the actual results. Another option might be to find a third party validation library, and keep yourself from getting bogged down in stuff like this.

Comment: Yep, I have run it. My approach may be "unreadable" ;) (per Alexei) but it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Actually this is probably wrong answer - so keeping it just so people not suggest the same thing - figuring out tokenization for "South East" is task in itself. Also I still doubt RegExp will be very usable either.

Original answer:
Don't... your initial RegExp attempt is already non-readable.

Dictionary look up for each word you want from the tokenized string ("brute force approach") already  gives you linear time on length and constant time per word. And it is very easy to customize with new words.

Comment: Ah, and unfortunately that is a real occurrence, as in ([redacted] actual user input): `#### -redact- STREET SOUTH EAST`

Comment: Actually...that might not be so bad. "South East" would be a subset of the matches for the single end word "east". I'd just check the second-to-last word if the last word already matched "east" or "west"...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer: My first implementation using a dictionary executed 30% faster than the regex version, and is far more readable and maintainable. Using short-circuited logic it still efficiently checks for (and finds) two-word compound directions like "south east".

Answer (score 0):

```
(^[nesw][^n\s]*)|([nesw][^n\s]*$)
```

So this will match a line that:

- begins or ends with a word that:

  - Begins with a cardinal direction
  - Doesn't have an n otherwise in it (to get rid of the "-ern"s)

Comment: I need to match (and extract) the entire direction string. And the direction can be spelled out, too, like "south" or even "south east" with a space.

Comment: It will also match any word starting with `[nesw]` at the beginning of the string. Like `nothing should match`.

Comment: @jmh_gr It will match the entire direction string, but not with a space. As has been mentioned, that is non-trivial. Regex may not be what you want.

Comment: @ChrisWue Yes, a slight downside, but it is much simpler. But I would guess that that would be a rarer case. If false positives are unacceptable, this wouldn't work. Also, his current regex has the same problem.

Comment: @McKay My current regex does not have that problem. Not that before I apply it, I add anchor and word-boundary modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Perl/PCRE compatible expression:

```
(?xi)
(^)?
\b
(?:
  n(?:orth)?
  (?:\s* (?: e(?:ast)? | w(?:est)? ))?
|
  s(?:outh)?
  (?:\s* (?: e(?:ast)? | w(?:est)? ))?
|
  e(?:ast)?
|
  w(?:est)?
)
\b
(?(1)|$)
```

I think C# supports all the features used here.

Comment: Just confirming: Yes that does work verbatim. The .NET regex engine executes it slightly slower than my pattern over several hundred thousand records, but it's not significantly slower.